# Can't work with live model srmklive-paypal

Tags: php, laravel, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working with srmk/paypal package 1.0.

Been working with this awesome package for some months in sandbox mode, yet I've been struggling to work with live mode.

I've been all over the issues others had and elsewhere and haven't been able to find a solution for this.

If I remove sandbox credentials I get an infinite loop right after `dd($response)` from `$response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($checkoutData);`

I'm using 1.0 so ExpressCheckout should not be the problem

I've tested on live server with same results.

My config

```
return [
    'mode'    => 'live', // Can only be 'sandbox' Or 'live'. If empty or invalid, 'live' will be used.
    'sandbox' => [
        'username'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD', ''),
        'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET', ''),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
        'app_id'      => 'APP-80W284485P519543T', // Used for testing Adaptive Payments API in sandbox mode
    ],
    'live' => [
        'username'    => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'    => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_PASSWORD', ''),
        'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_SECRET', ''),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
        'app_id'      => '', // Used for Adaptive Payments API
    ],

    'payment_action' => 'Sale', // Can only be 'Sale', 'Authorization' or 'Order'
    'currency'       => env('PAYPAL_CURRENCY', 'MXN'),
    'billing_type'   => 'MerchantInitiatedBilling',
    'notify_url'     => '', // Change this accordingly for your application.
    'locale'         => env('PAYPAL_LOCALE', 'es_ES'), // force gateway language  i.e. it_IT, es_ES, en_US ... (for express checkout only)
    'validate_ssl'   => false, // Validate SSL when creating api client.
];
```

env and env.example

```
#PayPal Setting & API Credentials - sandbox
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME=sb-tr4z02598960_api1.business.example.com
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD=VSYUE32AU7MT7VY4
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET=ACdNh.ieqXXfGzIFBkj6F-fUdA49AIBmvpyOyz5MhLCsLyQVdcB74zVJ
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE=

#PayPal Setting & API Credentials - live
PAYPAL_LIVE_API_USERNAME=********************api1.gmail.com
PAYPAL_LIVE_API_PASSWORD=**********************K9W
PAYPAL_LIVE_API_SECRET=******************************FCBABE
PAYPAL_LIVE_API_CERTIFICATE= storage_path('cert_key_pem.txt'); // also tested empty
```

I use the new API credentials provided by PayPal

```
public function  getExpressCheckout ($orderId) {

$checkoutData = $this->checkoutData($orderId); 
$provider = new ExpressCheckout();
$response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($checkoutData);

dd($response);

return redirect($response['paypal_link']);

}

private function checkoutData($orderId)
{
$cart = \Cart::getContent();
$cart2 = \Cart::getTotal();

$cartItems = array_map( function($item){
    return [
        'name' => $item['name'],
        'price' => $item['price'],
        'qty' => $item['quantity']
    ];
}, $cart->toarray());


$checkoutData = [
    'items' => $cartItems,
    'return_url' => route('paypal.success', $orderId),
    'cancel_url' => route('paypal.cancel'),
    'invoice_id' => uniqid(),
    'invoice_description' => 'order description',
    'total' => $cart2
];

return $checkoutData;
}

public function getExpressCheckoutSuccess(Request $request, $orderId)
{
$token = $request->get('token');
$payerId = $request->get('PayerID');
$provider = new ExpressCheckout();
$checkoutData = $this->checkoutData($orderId);

$response = $provider->getExpressCheckoutDetails($token);

if (in_array(strtoupper($response['ACK']),['SUCCESS','SUCCESSWITHWARNING'])) {

    $payment_status = $provider->doExpressCheckoutPayment($checkoutData,$token,$payerId);
    $status = $payment_status['PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS'];

    if (in_array($status, ['Completed','Processed'])) {
        $order = Order::find($orderId);
        $order->is_paid = 1;
        $order->save();

        Mail::to($order->buyer_email)->send(new OrderMail($order));

        \Cart::clear();

        return view ('newOrder.success', compact('order'));
    }
```

The infinite loop pops when calling this function from the package

```
private function doPayPalRequest($method)
    {
        // Setup PayPal API Request Payload
        $this->createRequestPayload($method);

        try {
            // Perform PayPal HTTP API request.
            $response = $this->makeHttpRequest();

            // dd($response); // I'm stuck here

            return $this->retrieveData($method, $response);
        } catch (Throwable $t) {
            $message = collect($t->getTrace())->implode('\n');
        }

        return [
            'type'    => 'error',
            'message' => $message,
        ];
    }
```

Thanks all,

Comment: Well what is the response? Where are you redirecting to? Is the 'infinite loop' you describe a 'too many redirects' in the browser?

Comment: Hey, I'm getting the infinite loop in the doPayPalRequest method. Just added into the description. Thanks.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution yet? I've got the same problem, setExpressCheckout goes into a infinite loop (only tried sandbox mode).

Comment: Yeah its working now. Remember to set `validate_ssl => false` in credentials.